# How to send multiple string by POST

Tags: php, html, post

Hi I am sending string using the below ;

`http://cleanlead.dlg.co.uk/?circuit=public&fuseaction=lead&Campid=629&Suppid=547&Surveyid=5&Title=Mr&Forename=Value &Surname=Value&Address1=Value &Postcode=Value &Energycosts_telephone=Possibly&EnergySwitch_PayMethod_Telephone=Yes&EnergySwitch_ElectricityProvider=Co-operative Energy&EnergySwitch_GasProvider=Southern Electricity&TelephoneORMobile=Value`

where I am getting success response. Problem is I want to send multiple string of the same how  sending different value in one time , how can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean `multiple string of the same` ? Do you meant the same label but numerous values etc. as array like? Also how you're sending this string? JS, form? Also note that the method you're using (GET) has size limitations problem and a i don't like the size of your url.

Comment: concatenate the strings using php concatenation method.

Comment: I am using an application called postman to send the post , am trying to send multiple post of the same with different values .

Answer (score 1):

Put `[]` after the name to indicate that the server should create an array of all the values. This needs to be URL-encoded as `%5B%5D`:

```
http://hostname/?name%5B%5D=value1&name%5B5D=value2&name%5B5D=value3
```

In PHP you will then be able to access these as elements of the array `$_GET['name']`.